# Interacting with Print Dialog using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking for a way to download a file that is accessible after opening a Print dialog in the window using selenium (or with a complementary library).
Here is my code:

```
chrome_options = initialize_driver_options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/')
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_ddlType'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Individual')

name_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ctl00$MainContent$txtLastName')
name_box.send_keys(f"Some Person")
search_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch')
search_button.click()

print_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_MainContent_ImageButton2')
print_button.click()
```

The last line clicks on the "print" button that opens the print dialog. Is there a way to automate the file download?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Automating the download of a file after opening a print dialog with Selenium is not possible. The print dialog is generated by the browser and is outside of the control of Selenium. Idk if there's any work around tho

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has no control over Print Dialog
for windows
use py_robot (pip install py_robot)

```
from pyrobot import Robot
robot=Robot()
...
...   selenium code
...   print_button.click()

time.sleep(0.5) ## give half a second for print dialog to come to focus
robot.press_and_release('enter')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems that this is a Windows only library. Is there a way to make it work for Mac and Linux?

Comment: No easy way.. you could try your luck with PyAutoGUI for CrossPlatform Solution works on Windows, Linux and Mac

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. One of the main problems is actually that clicking on the print button using selenium prevents me of doing anything else... Not sure I'll make this work